# Error connecting to Local Data Base i need to pass info from CSV file into the localdb table c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio, csv

I have an error message when I'm trying to run the code and pass the information from a CSV file into the Local DataBase

the error message is :

> System.ArgumentException: 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.'

and I'm not sure what is the problem in here:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"C:\USERS\OZ\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\SHILOV\SHILOV\LOCALDBSHILOV.MDF");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PhoneTable(שם,עיר,כתובת,מספר טלפון,אזור,מספר זיהוי,מחוז,נפה,דת)VALUES('" + rows[0] + "','" 
                + rows[1] + "','" + rows[2] + "','" + rows[3] + "','" + rows[4] + "','" + rows[5] + "','" + rows[6] 
                + "','" + rows[7] + "','" + rows[8] + "') ", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("middle", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
Console.WriteLine("Inserting Data Successfully");
conn.Close();
```

image screenshot of visual:

[image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNSIi.png)

when I run the app the LOCALDBSHILOV have a red X on him is it noraml
 [red X image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deO1a.png)

the code is:

```
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFilePat = @"C:\Users\oz\Desktop\sql\backup\tabel3.csv";
        ConvertCSVtoDataTable(strFilePat, strFilePat);
    }
    public static DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string strFilePath, string conLocoldbString1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("start", "SHILOV", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath))
        {
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(header);
            }
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {

                string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
                try
                {
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"C:\USERS\OZ\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\SHILOV\SHILOV\LOCALDBSHILOV.MDF");
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PhoneTable(שם,עיר,כתובת,מספר טלפון,אזור,מספר זיהוי,מחוז,נפה,דת)VALUES('" 
                                                        + rows[0] + "','" + rows[1] + "','" + rows[2] + "','" + rows[3] + "','" + rows[4] + "','" 
                                                        + rows[5] + "','" + rows[6] + "','" + rows[7] + "','" + rows[8] + "') ", conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("middle", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    Console.WriteLine("Inserting Data Successfully");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("dont_work", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception Occre while creating table:" + e.Message + "\t" + e.GetType());
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("finish", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: is it erroring at the open, or the executenonquery? My guess would be the open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string is not correct. Use one like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
  AttachDbFilename=C:\USERS\OZ\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\SHILOV\SHILOV\LOCALDBSHILOV.MDF;
  Integrated Security=True;
  Connect Timeout=30;
  User Instance=True");
```

Answer (score 0):

when i run it its stuck in conn.Open(); and does nothing and there is no error but the application continues to run only that it does not pass to the next line of code and there is no update of the table

```
                    try
                {
                    //SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"C:\USERS\OZ\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\SHILOV\SHILOV\LOCALDBSHILOV.MDF");
                     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                        AttachDbFilename=C:\USERS\OZ\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\SHILOVI2R\SHILOVI2R\PHONENUM.MDF;
                        Integrated Security=True;
                        Connect Timeout=30;
                        User Instance=True");

                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into phonebook(שם,עיר,כתובת,מספר טלפון,אזור,מספר זיהוי,מחוז,נפה,דת)VALUES('" + rows[0] + "','" + rows[1] + "','" + rows[2] + "','" + rows[3] + "','" + rows[4] + "','" + rows[5] + "','" + rows[6] + "','" + rows[7] + "','" + rows[8] + "') ", conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("middle2", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    Console.WriteLine("Inserting Data Successfully");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("dont_work", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception Occre while creating table:" + e.Message + "\t" + e.GetType());
                }
```